# IBM Worklight - "getSkinName is not defined"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime, worklight-skins

I am trying to define a new android.tablet skin. I am testing with a Nexus 7 running KitKat.

I did this:

1. Added the Skin
2. updated `getSkinName()` function
3. I can see in LogCat the function `getSkinName()` being called

However, there is a confusing message:

> "default" skin will be used, because skin named android.tablet was not
>   found. Add a skin or change android/js/skinLoader.js to return
>   existing skin.

Am I missing something?

> 04-01 17:03:32.969: D/CordovaNetworkManager(4481): Connection Type:
>   wifi 04-01 17:03:32.969: D/CordovaActivity(4481):
>   onMessage(networkconnection,wifi) 04-01 17:03:32.969:
>   D/CordovaLog(4481):
>   file:///android_asset/www/default/js/skinLoader.js: Line 18 : 
>   screen.width 800 04-01 17:03:32.969: I/chromium(4481):
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(18)] " screen.width 800", source:
>   file:///android_asset/www/default/js/skinLoader.js (18)
>   **04-01 17:03:32.969: D/CordovaLog(4481): file:///android_asset/www/default/js/skinLoader.js: Line 23 : 
>   returned skinName is android.tablet** 04-01 17:03:32.969:
>   I/chromium(4481): [INFO:CONSOLE(23)] " returned skinName is
>   android.tablet", source:
>   file:///android_asset/www/default/js/skinLoader.js (23) 04-01
>   17:03:32.969: **W/WLDroidGap(4481): "default" skin will be used,
>   because skin named android.tablet was not found. Add a skin or change
>   android/js/skinLoader.js to return existing skin.** ... ... ... 04-01
>   17:03:34.779: D/CordovaLog(4481):
>   file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/cordova.js: Line 1034 :
>   processMessage failed: Error: ReferenceError: getSkinName is not
>   defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're right, Worklight Skins fail to load - at least on the first load of the application; if you load it a second time, it does work.

---

I've opened a defect for this issue.
If you are an IBM business partner or customer, please open a PMR so that once fixed you'll be able to receive this in the form of an iFix release.

---

Here's what I've done:

1. Created a new project and application
2. Added the Android environment
3. Added an application skin, android.skin, to the Android environment
4. Added a `main.css` to my-app\android.skin\css with `body {background-color:red}`
5. Changed `getSkinName()` in my-app\android\js\skinLoader.js' to `return "android.skin"`
6. Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server
7. Run As > Android application

The first load indeed loads the "default" skin instead of "android.skin". The second time I loaded the app (from the device, not by re-installing the app), it did load the "android.skin"...

So anyway, there's a defect. But you can continue developing your application albeit in a somewhat inconvenient way...

Comment: Thanks Idan. I will open a PMR.