# Worklight Runtime Skins - getSkinName not working properly

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime, worklight-skins

I am creating a sample for Worklight Runtime Skins for Android device by referring link "http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/05_03_Supporting_multiple_form_factors_using_Worklight_skins.pdf". I have changed JS,CSS and HTML for applying skin on phone/tablet, and the same is tested to work fine via Worklight Preview.

But when I try to run the same code in real device I am not getting proper output as expected. The reason for that is 'getSkinName()' functionality in skinLoader.js is not returning valid result. 
       I tried using following code for detecting if a device is mobile or tablet, but both functions gave invalid outputs.

Detect Device using UserAgent: //Always returns 'android.phone' skin.

```
function getSkinName() { 
        var userAgent = navigator.userAgent; 
        var skinName = "default"; 
        alert(userAgent); 
        //android tablet 
        if(userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") != -1 && 
            userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("mobile") == -1){ 
            skinName = "default"; 
            alert("tablet!"); 
        } 
        //android phone 
        else if(userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") != -1 && 
            userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("mobile") != -1){ 
            skinName = "android.phone"; 
            alert("phone!"); 
        } 

        return skinName; 
}
```

Detect Device using width of device: //Not working properly across  orientation

```
 function getSkinName() { 
        var skinName = "default"; 
        var hres = screen.width || window.innerWidth || 320; 
        var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1; 
        if (ratio == 0) { 
               ratio = 1; 
        } 
        var virtWidth = hres / ratio; 
        if (virtWidth >= 640) { 
              skinName = "android.tablet"; 
        } 
    return skinName; 
 }
```

Please share thoughts on correcting getSkinName() for proper functioning.

Comment: Please verify you are not experiencing this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797125/ibm-worklight-getskinname-is-not-defined

Comment: did you check the above?

Comment: So was there any response from Worklight team for the query raised Idan?

Comment: (I am part of that team), yes, this defect is resolved in the latest iFix for Worklight 6.1.0.1; can you confirm this is what you are experiencing? That is, after the second time you load the app, it works as expected?

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing may be related to the defect mentioned in this question: [IBM Worklight - "getSkinName is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797125/ibm-worklight-getskinname-is-not-defined)

The fix for the mentioned defect is available in the latest iFix release for Worklight 6.1.0.1.
If you are an IBM customer or business partner, you can obtain it from IBM Fix Central (or via a PMR support request).